# Binding Custom FontFamilys to a list of TextBlocks

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm pretty sure I'm going about this the wrong way but any help to push me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Basically, I'm trying to add a list of custom fonts and then display them in a list of TextBlocks but no matter how many different ways I try it, I keep getting this same error, which doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

> Error: BindingExpression path error: 'FontFamilyList' property not found on 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.FontFamily'. BindingExpression: Path='FontFamilyList' DataItem='Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.FontFamily'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='FontSelector'); target property is 'FontFamily' (type 'FontFamily')

The end result should be 24 TextBlocks in a row, each containing the string "abcdef", but each one in a different font.

Here is what I've tried so far.

**Class**

```
public static class CustomFonts
{
    public static FontFamily sketchy = new FontFamily("/Assets/font/a_bit_sketchy.ttf#sketchy");
    public static FontFamily adam = new FontFamily("/Assets/font/adam.cg_pro.otf#adam");
    public static FontFamily addled = new FontFamily("/Assets/font/addled.TTF#addled");
    public static FontFamily adventure = new FontFamily("/Assets/font/adventure.ttf#adventure");
    public static FontFamily agentorange = new FontFamily("/Assets/font/agentorange#agentorange");
    public static FontFamily arial = new FontFamily("/Assets/font/arial.ttf#arial");
    public static FontFamily bira = new FontFamily("/Assets/font/bira.ttf#bira");
    public static FontFamily blueprint = new FontFamily("/Assets/font/blueprint.otf#blueprint");
    public static FontFamily branbollFet = new FontFamily("/Assets/font/branbollFet.ttf#branbollFet");
    public static FontFamily budmo = new FontFamily("/Assets/font/budmo_jiggler.otf#budmo");
    public static FontFamily childs = new FontFamily("/Assets/font/childs.ttf#childs");
    public static FontFamily collegiate = new FontFamily("/Assets/font/collegiate.ttf#collegiate");
    public static FontFamily comesinhandy = new FontFamily("/Assets/font/comesinhandy.ttf#comesinhandy");
    public static FontFamily dknanuk = new FontFamily("/Assets/font/dk_nanuk.otf#dknanuk");
    public static FontFamily itcedscr = new FontFamily("/Assets/font/itcedscr.TTF#itcedscr");
    public static FontFamily levi = new FontFamily("/Assets/font/levi_brush.TTF#levi");
    public static FontFamily lobster = new FontFamily("/Assets/font/lobster.otf#lobster");
    public static FontFamily missionscript = new FontFamily("/Assets/font/mission_script.otf#mission");
    public static FontFamily moonbold = new FontFamily("/Assets/font/moon_bold.otfmoonbold");
    public static FontFamily moonlight = new FontFamily("/Assets/font/moon_light.otf#moonlight");
    public static FontFamily permanentmarker = new FontFamily("/Assets/font/permanentmarker.ttf#permanent");
    public static FontFamily phosphate = new FontFamily("/Assets/font/phosphate.ttc#phosphate");
    public static FontFamily ralewaydots = new FontFamily("/Assets/font/raleway_dots.ttf#raleway");
    public static FontFamily rosewood = new FontFamily("/Assets/font/rosewood.otf#rosewood");

    public static List<FontFamily> FontFamilyList;

    public static List<FontFamily> PopulateFonts()
    {
        FontFamilyList = new List<FontFamily>
        {
            sketchy,
            adam,
            addled,
            adventure,
            agentorange,
            arial,
            bira,
            blueprint,
            branbollFet,
            budmo,
            childs,
            collegiate,
            comesinhandy,
            dknanuk,
            itcedscr,
            levi,
            lobster,
            missionscript,
            moonbold,
            moonlight,
            permanentmarker,
            phosphate,
            ralewaydots,
            rosewood
        };
        return FontFamilyList;
    }
}
```

**Set ItemsSource**

```
public DesignView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    FontList.ItemsSource = CustomFonts.PopulateFonts();
}
```

**XAML**

```
<Grid Height="150" Margin="0,270,0,0">
    <Image Source="ms-appx:///Resources/Elements/prev_250.png" Height="100" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></Image>
    <ListView Name="FontList" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomFonts}"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
                ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled="True" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Margin="100,270,100,20"
                Height="70" AutomationProperties.SizeOfSet="24">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Name="FontSelector" Text="abcdef" Grid.Column="0" Height="70" Width="70" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="{Binding FontFamilyList}">
                    </TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <Image Source="ms-appx:///Resources/Elements/next_250.png" Height="100" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Image>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Just an idea: Can you just initialize your FontFamilyList with the `public static List<FontFamily> FontFamilyList = new List<FontFamily>...` and then bind to that?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but yeah I've tried that already and got the same error. I think the issue is in the XAML and the way I'm binding it, but I've binded other similar lists the same way (not FontFamilys though).

Comment: Have you tried referencing the fonts in the list manually? Just to try and see if the list actually works as intended? I can't test it at the moment but may test it later when I'm home.

Comment: Yes, I'm able to assign a CustomFont to a single TexBlock correctly so I'm pretty sure I'm binding incorrectly.

Comment: Why is `CustomForms` Static? Just to Populate Fonts? Or for some other reason?

Comment: @AVK It doesn't need to be static, I was basically just trying everything to get it to work. I set them to static just to test that the fonts actually worked.

Comment: @AdamMcMahon See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a simple project to see why there is an issue and how it works. as @eberthold mentioned, you have overridden the `ItemsSource` that is working from UI. Instead of that you can Just Bind the DataContext. Also you do not have to have an add'l method to create a List. You can do that in the constructor of the class.

I changed your class from `Static` to `Non-Static`. To test, i added System Fonts to list.

```
public class CustomFonts
{
    public FontFamily sketchy = new FontFamily("/Assets/font/a_bit_sketchy.ttf#sketchy");
    public FontFamily adam = new FontFamily("/Assets/font/adam.cg_pro.otf#adam");
    public FontFamily addled = new FontFamily("/Assets/font/addled.TTF#addled");
    public FontFamily adventure = new FontFamily("/Assets/font/adventure.ttf#adventure");
    ...

    public List<FontFamily> FontFamilyList { get; set; }

    public CustomFonts()
    {
        FontFamilyList = new List<FontFamily>
        {
            new FontFamily("Times New Roman"),
            new FontFamily("Monotype Corsiva"),
            new FontFamily("Cambria"),
            new FontFamily("Calibri")
        };

        //FontFamilyList = new List<FontFamily>
        //{
        //    sketchy,
        //    adam,
        //    addled,
        //    adventure,
        ///   ....
        //};
    }
}
```

This is my XAML

```
<Grid>
    <ListView Name="FontList" AutomationProperties.SizeOfSet="24" ItemsSource="{Binding FontFamilyList}">
        <ListView.DataContext>
            <app4:CustomFonts />
        </ListView.DataContext>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="ABCDEF" FontFamily="{Binding }"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

So I am setting the `DataContext` of `FontList` in XAML to the `CustomFonts` class directly. Then i am binding the `FontFamiltList` Property directly to ItemsSoure. Since you want to bind the FontFamily to `TextBox`'s `FontFamily` Property, and that is the element inside the list, it will be just `{Binding }`

Below is the output.

[image]

Comment: This works well and very well explained. Thank you :)

Comment: @AdamMcMahon Glad i could be of help.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell you messed up your Binding/DataContext

In XAML you specified the ItemsSource to be your CustomFonts class

```
<ListView Name="FontList" ItemsSource="{Binding CustomFonts}"
```

The DesingView code destroys this binding and sets a List as ItemsSource - which for me seems to be the correct ItemsSource

```
FontList.ItemsSource = CustomFonts.PopulateFonts();
```

Because of that, your have a different DataContext in your DataTemplate.
As specified by XAML your list will have one item with DataContext CustomFont.
Your DesignView will have 24 Items with DataContext FontFamily.

To make your DesignView work your will have to update your binding of FontFamily inside the DataTemplate to

```
<TextBlock Name="FontSelector" Text="abcdef" Grid.Column="0" Height="70" Width="70" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="{Binding}">
```

Comment: Very nicely explained, but unfortunately this doesn't work either. I no longer get the error message, but no items are displayed in my ListView.